# 'hhighlighter' wrapper script saying command not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, terminal, kali-linux

I have gotten the wrapper script 'hhighlighter' from https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter which colors anything you want in stdout. I followed the instructions about installing ack-grep, created alias for ack=ack-grep in ~/.bashrc, put the h() function in ~/.bashrc, everything works fine when typing in the terminal. But when putting the EXACT same commands in a bash script, it says command not found. I will give examples here...

```
root@kali:~# echo "abcd" | h a b c d
abcd
```

Here is what my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash  
echo "abcd" | h a b c d
```

Exactly like the command typed in, but here is the output when running the script

```
root@kali:~# ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 1: h: command not found
```

How could this work when typing directly in the terminal, but not when having the exact same command in a bash script? If my ~/.bashrc is needed or anything else is needed to solve this please let me know, its been going on 4 days now without figuring this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: When bash is started non-interactively then it does not read `~/.bashrc`.

Thus you have to read `h()` from the script.

If you want to use aliases in a script then you have to

1. enable the use of aliases in the script with `shopt -s expand_aliases`
2. define the alias in the script.

An alternative to an alias is defining a shell function (which works the same in interactive and non-interactive shells):

```
foo () {
  bar "$@"
}
```

But it is not possible to take over alias or function definitions from the running shell into a script as the shell running the script is re-initialized.

Comment: So should i put the h() function in my bash script instead of my ~/.bashrc file? The instructions here https://github.com/paoloantinori/hhighlighter say to put the h() function in the ~/.bashrc file.....

Comment: I put the h() function in my bash script, and now its telling me the 'ack' command cannot be found. I have ack-grep installed for my distro not ack, and so I made an alias inside my ~/.bashrc -- alias ack='ack-grep'...I even typed it in the terminal before running the command but still says ack - command not found...

Comment: @WillHughes I have extended the answer.

Comment: I reworded the question to hopefully make more sense, and simplify it a little.

Comment: @WillHughes I have told you everything you need to know. Obviously you don't do what I explained in my answer.

Comment: I put the shopt -s expand_aliases in my script along with the alias, didn't work, actually made it worse because when taking the alias out of ~/.bashrc the commands wouldn't even work directly in the terminal anymore. I put the h() function directly in the bash script, didn't work, again made it worse bec wouldn't even work directly in terminal...So yes I did both suggestions and they didn't work, thats why I reworked the question...

Comment: @WillHughes There is no reason to delete the alias and function definitions in `~/.bashrc`. You may copy them to the script or import the file there (**after** enabling alias expansion). A statement like "I put the shopt -s expand_aliases in my script along with the alias" doesn't help much as it doesn't tell us what exactly you have done. Obviously you have done it wrong somehow. And "didn't work" is equally useless without an explanation what happened (error message).

Comment: Your right...I didn't put the shopt -s expand_aliases, the alias, and the h() function in my test script all at one time...I got myself mixed up with all the solutions I was trying. Sorry for the misunderstanding, and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Solution that helped me was to force the script to run in interactive mode with a `#!/bin/bash -i` header.

Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide [warns](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html) about weird consequences though:

> Be aware that this can cause erratic script behavior or show error
>   messages even when no error is present.

However I haven't observed anything like this.